XAML CarouselView Horizontal and Vertical Functionality
I am working on a maui app (VS 2022) and have a ResourcePage.xaml which has a number of boxes (frames?), one of which is the custodian one. This box has a carouselview (which isn't working) and if a record is retrieved with more than one custodian, they are supposed to be accessed via a horizontal scroll in the carousel. Below is the part of the code relevant to the question;
<Frame Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" BorderColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="242.67">
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- Vertical ScrollView -->
                        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="5" HeightRequest="485.34">
                                <!-- Double the height -->
                                <!-- Top Half - Custodian Info -->
                                <StackLayout x:Name="PlaceholderContent" Padding="10" Spacing="5" IsVisible="True">
                                    <Image Source="custodian_icon.png" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                                    <Label Text="Custodian Info" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                    <Label Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="FullName: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="{Binding FullCustodianNameWithMiddleName}" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="Reference: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="{Binding C_REFERENCE}" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="Type: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="{Binding SC_TYPE}" />
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <!-- Horizontal Line Divider -->
                                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" Margin="0,10,0,10" />

                                <!-- Bottom Half - Additional Info -->
                                <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="5">
                                    <Label Text="Additional Info" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                    <Label Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="Phone: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="N/A" />
                                                <!-- Placeholder text -->
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="Email: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                <Span Text="N/A" />
                                                <!-- Placeholder text -->
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>

                        <!-- CarouselView moved to the top of the box -->
                        <CarouselView x:Name="CustodianCarousel" ItemsSource="{Binding Custodians}" VerticalOptions="Start" Loop="False" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsVisible="True">
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Padding="10">
                                        <!-- Define Grid Rows for Layout -->
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <!-- Define Grid Column to avoid layout shifting -->
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!-- Icon -->
                                        <Image Source="custodian_icon.png" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="30,0,0,0" />

                                        <!-- Title -->
                                        <Label Text="Custodian Info" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />

                                        <!-- Full Name -->
                                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="FullName: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                    <Span Text="{Binding FullCustodianNameWithMiddleName}" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>

                                        <!-- Reference -->
                                        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Reference: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                    <Span Text="{Binding C_REFERENCE}" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>

                                        <!-- Type -->
                                        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                                <FormattedString>
                                                    <Span Text="Type: " FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                    <Span Text="{Binding SC_TYPE}" />
                                                </FormattedString>
                                            </Label.FormattedText>
                                        </Label>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CarouselView>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>

The layout within the box is split in two - top half shows basic info and the bottom half shows additional info. This part of the code works for one record as there is no need to scroll horizontally (only need to scroll vertically), however it doesn't work for instances when there is more than one custodian i.e. if a student has more than one custodian retrieved, I want to be able to scroll horizontally to access the different custodians, and when I view the custodian I want to be able to scroll vertically to view their additional info. Please pardon some of the incorrect terminology - XAML isn't my strongest suit and am learning as I go along. Any suggestions are welcome.

there are no row definitions defined for the parent grid??? is this the right code?, because  for me this displays carouselview on top of basic info...

Do you want to vertically scroll the content of each item in  the  CustodianCarousel ?

@liyu - thank you for the reply. Yes I want to vertically scroll the content of each custodian indeed.

@BhavaneshN - it's the right code I provided and the basic info and carousel do not overlap each other.

Why isn't scrollview used in DataTemplates ?

@liyu As mentioned in my post, I am fairly new to MAUI apps and .xaml in general, so I may have made some mistakes as I am self-teaching and may not be able to answer some of your questions. Any corrections or amendments are most welcome.

Change the content of the  DataTemplate  and use ScrollView to wrap the displayed content to scroll up and down.
